# Why is Windows installed on HDD instead of SSD on Lenovo Ideapad?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, lenovo-laptop

I bought a Lenovo Ideapad U410 and Windows was supposed to be installed on SSD, but it is on the HDD, instead. What is the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: most (if not all) laptops with 32GB SSD or less use the SSD as cache since if you install Windows to such small space you'll hear a lot of complains from customers

Answer (score 2):

Based on the specs, the model has only 32gb SSD and is used only as cache for better performance. Assuming you want Windows on the SSD, the 32gb space is just not enough space and is not recommended. Windows 8 64bit alone, requires 20 gb, and by the time you install the updates and the programs it could easily hit 32gb.

One option is to replace the 32gb SSD to at least 120gb or bigger depending on your needs and place your Windows there but the process a bit complicated.